# htaccess redirect not working on co.uk domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, virtualhost

Here is my apache configuration:

```
DocumentRoot "/www/public"

<Directory "/www/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAlias www.domain.com domain.com
        DocumentRoot /www/public
        ServerName www.domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAlias www.domain.co.uk domain.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /www/public
        ServerName www.domain.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is what my htaccess looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

If I access `www.domain.com`, `domain.com`, or `www.domain.co.uk` everything works fine. However, when I access `domain.co.uk`, it doesn't redirect properly to `www.domain.co.uk`. It seems like the `co.uk` requests are not reading my htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

That is due to the regex used in `www` adding rule. Change that to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.(?:[^.]+|co\.uk)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: here is the problem with that rule. i used to have it before, but i had to change because sometimes i need `subdomain.domain.com` but it redirects to `www.subdomain.domain.com` and that wont work. i need to rework that regex match to include.co.uk, im guessing the extra period is not matched

Comment: `subdomain.domain.com`  and `domain.co.uk` both have 3 components separated by DOT. So same regex won't be able to distinguish them. Better use it as: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain)\. [NC]`

Comment: i already posted a solution works just as i wanted. thanks for pointing out the problem though

Comment: Please do not post that as a solution as I've pinpointed the same problem in my answer. As I suggested there can be many regex variants to solve the problem once it is identified. If you want I include your variant also in my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to change the HTACCESS from:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
```

To

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^[^.]+\.[^.]+$|^[^.]+\.co\.uk$)
```